# How can I get Visual Studio 2013 to use a custom JSON schema?

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, jsonschema

I am working on a project that involves the use of JSON to store and retrieve data; in order to write some example data I am using VS2013's JSON editor, which supports, supposedly, the use of arbitrary JSON schema for its Intellisense code-completion feature.  However, I have not been able to get it to recognise any schemata that are not accessed through a website, e.g. http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema works fine but /JSON/mySchema.json does not.

It will not load /JSON/mySchema.json from the $schema tag, nor will it allow me to type in its name; whenever I type it into the schema box and hit enter, it returns the schema box to "No Schema Selected".

How do I get VS2013 to recognise my custom schema and generate Intellisense completion from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've learned (from comments on the announcement page for this functionality) that using relative paths for JSON schema is currently bugged in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3;

> "[...] the relative $schema path is not working in a non-web project and will be fixed in Update 4."

(from a comment on [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/11/intellisense-for-json-schema-in-the-json-editor.aspx))

It should work fine with an absolute path, but of course that's not portable.  Update 4 should be out soon; the RC is already out, and information can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2994375).

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm on VS2015 update 3, and get the message "the type of schema applied to the document is not supported."

Comment: I never did, sorry. I haven't had any need to work in Visual Studio since this project, so I don't know if it's been changed.

Comment: Looks like it is working: I just had my $schema value set wrong on my schema file.